# Image rendered well in eevee but not in cycles

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, video

I've just created a character and I've rendered the image in cycles and in Eevee. Point is that with EEvee I don't see any problem,but with Cycles I see that the face let see what's inside the mouth,that's the teeth. Also I see an odd gray coloring at the cheeks. Can u give a look at the pictures below ? thanks.

This is how looks the image rendered with cycles :

[image: cycles]

this is eevee :

[image: eevee]

Comment: Might be the shader, might be overlapping geometry, hard to say based on the provided images...

Comment: can I provide some information to help to identify the problem ? maybe u can give a look at the shaders of the face and the teeth,here ? ---> https://drive.google.com/open?id=10IXmyjtizj78d_aSOIaRknHHwRigDl5L

Comment: how can be the overlapping geometry ? if there is,it should be visibile also when I render the image in eevee.

Comment: Without the file it's hard to guess what's wrong actually. One thing you can try is removing the texture which is plugged into the alpha socket. Also *Body Reflection* as well as *Skin Body Diffuse.001* should not be set to *non-color data*. Start with the base color only, see whether that works and test all other images step by step...

Comment: I tried to follow your directions,but I haven't been able to fix the error. Can u give a look at the file here ? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FnCdNt_FvzOSq7Cz8ZRU77sQmFt2dR3Z

Comment: Yep, it's caused by the texture plugged into the alpha socket of the principled shader (`std_skin_head` material): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAhuP.png It probably gets ignored in eevee, not sure.

Comment: I did the same as you did,but I get a different result,like this : https://imgur.com/bcYMIlz ; worst than your.

Comment: You are still watching the result of the material preview. Switch to render preview and judge from there (Click on the ball icon on the top right of the 3d viewport)...

Comment: like this ? : https://imgur.com/KL2A56f ; it seems not good